# Angular - при прокрутке страницы менять активные пункты меню

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Задача: добавлять/удалять класс active элементам меню в aside:
1) при прокрутке страниц;
2) при клике по элементам меню.
Пример того, что хочется получить - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gHoAt/

Код:
**aside.html**

```
<nav ng-if="state.is('ui.uikit.kendo') || state.is('ui.uikit.charts')">
<ul class="menu-v">
    <li class="level-1"><span><strong>KENDO CONTROLS</strong></span></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendo#textinputs">Text inputs</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendo#selects">Selects</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendo#datetimepickers">Date and time picker</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendo#panelbar">Panel bar</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendo#tabs">Tabs</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendo#editor">Editor</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendo#buttons">Buttons</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/kendo#grid">Grid</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><span><strong>KENDO CHARTS</strong></span></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#areacharts">Area charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#barcharts">Bar Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#boxplotcharts">Box Plot Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#bubblecharts">Bubble Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#bulletcharts">Bullet Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#donutcharts">Donut Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#funnelcharts">Funnel Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#linecharts">Line charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#piecharts">Pie Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#polarcharts">Polar charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#radarcharts">Radar charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#sparklines">Sparklines</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#rangecharts">Range Bar Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#scattercharts">Scatter Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#stockcharts">Stock Charts</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#treemap">TreeMap</a></li>
    <li class="level-1"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#waterfallcharts">Waterfall Charts</a></li>
</ul>
```

**app.js**

```
'use strict';

// Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
angular.module('qcp', [
    'ui.router',
    'qcp.filters',
    'qcp.services',
    'qcp.directives',
    'qcp.controllers',
    'hljs'
])

.run(function ($rootScope, InjectCss, $log, $state, $timeout, $location) {

    var styles = {

        'base': {
            before: [
                'css/kendo/kendo.common.min.css',
                'css/kendo/kendo.nova.css'
            ],
            after: []
        },

        'sphere': {
            before: [
                'css/kendo/kendo.common.min.css',
                'css/kendo/kendo.sphere.css'
            ],
            after: ['css/ui.sphere.css']
        },

        'express': {
            before: [
                'css/kendo/kendo.common.min.css',
                'css/kendo/kendo.express.css'
            ],
            after: ['css/ui.express.css']
        },

        'sberbank': {
            before: [
                'css/kendo/kendo.common.min.css',
                'css/kendo/kendo.sberbank.css'
            ],
            after: ['css/ui.sberbank.css']
        },

        'beeline': {
            before: [
                'css/kendo/kendo.common.min.css'
                , 'css/kendo/kendo.beeline.css'
            ]
            , after: ['css/ui.beeline.css']
        }
    };

    $rootScope.state = $state;
    $rootScope.changeTheme = function (themeName) {
        $rootScope.skin = themeName;
        var styleBandle = styles[themeName];
        $log.log('ui change theme to', themeName);
        return InjectCss.setCss(styleBandle);
    };

    $rootScope.themeUrl = function (themeName) {
        return $state.href($state.current.name, {currentTheme: themeName});
    };

    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
        $timeout(function(){
            UiKitJQinit();
        }, 1)
    });

})

.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/base/ui");

    $stateProvider.state('ui', {
        url: '/:currentTheme',
        abstract: true,
        views:{
            /*'toolbar' : {templateUrl:'partials/layouts/toolbar.html'},*/
            'aside'   : {templateUrl:'partials/layouts/aside.html'},
            'header'  : {templateUrl:'partials/layouts/header.html'},
            'main'    : {template   :'<div ui-view></div>'}
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$log', 'theme', '$stateParams', function ($scope, $log, theme, $state) {
            $scope.$state = $state;
        }],
        resolve: {
            theme: ['InjectCss', '$stateParams', '$rootScope',
                function (InjectCss, $stateParams, $rootScope) {
                    return $rootScope.changeTheme($stateParams.currentTheme)
                }]
        }
    });

    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit'             , {url: '/ui'                , templateUrl: 'partials/uikit.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.all'         , {url: '/all'               , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/all.html'}}});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.reset'       , {url: '/reset'             , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/reset.html'}}});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.iconsGlyph'  , {url: '/iconsGlyph'        , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/iconsGlyph.html'}}});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.controls'    , {url: '/controls'          , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/controls.html'}}});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.nav'         , {url: '/nav'               , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/nav.html'}}});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.list'        , {url: '/lists'             , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/lists.html'}}});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.layout'      , {url: '/layouts'           , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/layouts.html'}}});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.notices'     , {url: '/notices'           , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/uikit/notices.html'}}});

    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.kendo'       , {url: '/kendo'             , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/kendo/controls.html'}}});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.uikit.charts'      , {url: '/charts'            , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/kendo/charts.html'}}});

    $stateProvider.state('ui.widgets'           , {url: '/widgets'           , templateUrl: 'partials/widgets.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.services'          , {url: '/services'          , templateUrl: 'partials/services.html'});

    $stateProvider.state('ui.browsers'              , {url: '/browsers'              , templateUrl: 'partials/browsers/browsers.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.browsers.ie'       , {url: '/ie'                , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/browsers/ie.html'}}});

    $stateProvider.state('ui.errors'             , {url: '/error'             , templateUrl: 'partials/errors/error.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.errors.404'         , {url: '/404'               , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/errors/404.html'}}});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.errors.500'         , {url: '/500'               , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/errors/500.html'}}});

    $stateProvider.state('ui.informator'        , {url: '/product/informator', templateUrl: 'partials/informator/index.html'});

    $stateProvider.state('ui.login'             , {url: '/login'             , templateUrl: 'partials/login/index.html'});
    $stateProvider.state('ui.login.password'    , {url: '/password'          , views: {'@ui':{templateUrl: 'partials/login/password.html'}}});

});
```

Ищу вариант решения через AngularJS. Что сейчас имею (работаю только с событием клика):
**На примере двух элементов:**

```
<li class="level-1" ng-class="{'active': anchorHref=='piecharts'}" ng-click="piechartsHref()"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#piecharts">Pie Charts</a></li>
<li class="level-1" ng-class="{'active': anchorHref=='polarcharts'}" ng-click="polarchartsHref()"><a href="#{{skin}}/ui/charts#polarcharts">Polar charts</a></li>
```

**app.js**

```
$scope.hashPage = $location.hash();

$scope.piechartsHref = function()
{
    $scope.anchorHref = 'piecharts';
}
$scope.polarchartsHref = function()
{
    $scope.anchorHref = 'polarcharts';
}
```

Минусы того, что сейчас получается: 
1) Придется создавать к каждому элементу списка свою функцию (подобные polarchartsHref, piechartsHref) 
2) При начальной инициализации страницы, активному элементу меню не присваивается класс

Comment: суть та же, подписывайтесь на скролл, и в нужный момент - меняйте state. Хотя наверное тут такое не пройдет, если у вас полностью другая страница загружается

Comment: @Grundy - возьмем пример без загрузки новой страницы. скажите куда копать?

Comment: если _вся_ страница уже загружена, то единственное, что надо сделать - подписаться на событие _scroll_, и в нем проверить какой из элементов показывается. собственно в, приведенном по ссылке, примере так и делается: `$(window).scroll(function() {` подписка на событие, `if($(this).position().top <= windscroll + 10) {` проверка что сейчас видно

Comment: код лучше всего в вопрос добавлять, в комментариях его очень проблематично разобрать, если там большое одной операции

Comment: @Grundy обновил вопрос

Comment: ооооох... с кликом проще, вместо функций используйте `ng-click="anchorHref='piecharts'"` например для первого случая. начальная инициализация тоже просто - всегда выбирается первый элемент, то есть где-то в контроллере должна быть запись `$scope.anchorHref = currentHash;` - где _currentHash_ это как раз пункт который мы хотим подсветить